# algorithm to randomize a matrix with uniqueness constraint

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to develop an algorithm for randomizing an NxN matrix N times with the following constraint: any two values A and B can exist at most one time across all the columns in the resulting matrices. For example, a 3x3 matrix is randomized 3 times with the following result:

```
matrix #0
[0, 3, 6]
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]

matrix #1
[0, 3, 6]
[7, 1, 4]
[5, 8, 2]

matrix #2
[0, 3, 6]
[4, 7, 1]
[8, 2, 5]
```

The pairing of any two number A and B in any given column, say 0 and 1 in column 0 of matrix #0 are unique for all the columns in each resulting matrix. This condition must hold for every two-paired values in the matrices.

I developed what I believed was a solution with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

w,h = 5,5
matrix_list = []

def rotate(l,n):
    return l[-n:] + l[:-n]

def transpose(l):
    return list(map(list, zip(*l)))

matrix = [[x*w + y for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
#matrix = transpose(matrix)

for i in range(w):
    matrix_list.append(matrix[:])
    matrix = [rotate(matrix[n],n) for n in range(w)]

for m in matrix_list:
    for arr in m:
        print(arr)
    print('\n')
```

It simply shift the values of each row N places were N is the value of the row index of the matrix.

However, I found that the algorithm does not work whenever N is even and N > 2, as illustrated by the following partial output of a 4x4 matrix (the pairing of values in rows 0 and 2 are repeated):

```
(from matrix #0)
[0, 4, 8, 12]
[1, 5, 9, 13]
[2, 6, 10, 14]
[3, 7, 11, 15]

(from matrix #2)
[0, 4, 8, 12]
[9, 13, 1, 5]
[2, 6, 10, 14]
[11, 15, 3, 7]
```

I have tried all sorts of shifting and transposing methods and continue to come up empty. Any assistance in creating a solution for even-dimensioned matrices or a general solution covering both odd and even matrices would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just permute each row with `random.shuffle()`?

Comment: because random.shuffle() does not guarantee the required constraint.

Comment: In what sense is your intended solution a solution at all? You specified randomness but your algorithm is deterministic. In any event, perhaps you could look into the theory of experimental design.

Comment: Are you sure it's possible? Can you find a solution to the 4x4 case using brute force?

Comment: John, you are correct. It is deterministic. However, it does achieve the desired result. So perhaps my description of the problem was not accurate.

Comment: Alex, in my struggle to find a solution I have entertained the same thought: perhaps an NxN matrix cannot have N solutions that meets my constraint when N is even. That is a great question for the mathematicians among us.

Comment: Are there any other constraints? Nothing about your stated constraint requires that each value has to stay in the same row, but in all of your examples they do. Is that an unstated constraint?

Comment: it is not an unstated constraint. Because I am simply shifting the row values, the rows in the resulting matrices necessarily retain the same overall set of values.

Comment: If it isn't a constraint, then by restricting yourself to permutations of values within each row you are leaving much of the solution space unexplored. Perhaps `N` even requires the shuffling of some elements between different rows.

Comment: There are enough pairs of numbers available. Each column has choose(n,2) pairs and there are n columns in each grid and n grids, so you need a total of n * n * choose(n-2) pairs = (n^4 - n^3)/2. The total number of pairs is choose(n^2,2) = (n^4 - n^2) / 2.

The problem is that your technique 'wastes' a lot of pairs because you're only using pairs which are initially in different rows.

Comment: Not possible for 4x4.